# PHP Fatal error: Class ‘Couchbase’ not found when connect to server

Tags: couchbase

i have A B and C three servers.
A is centos 6.x on which couchbase server is installed.
B is my local server(localhost).
C is my other server on which i want to run my php script

i can run my script on B and Access server A. but when i am trying to connect A to c it throws error

> PHP Fatal error: Class ‘Couchbase’ not found

Answer (score 1):

it looks like an installation/classpath issue to me. Are you sure Couchbase PHP SDK is correctly installed on server C?

Comment: thanks Laurent.
now this issues is resolved. the cause was that there is a port error. we have not opened 80 port on server to communicate the php script.

but now i facing a new issue that is 
when i am running my script it throws an exception
>Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CouchbaseException' with message 'Client-Side timeout exceeded for operation. Inspect network conditions or increase the timeout' in

Comment: That still looks like a networking error. This might also occur because you're trying to connect to an unexisting bucket.